# passing empty field as parameter in jasper ireport

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jasper-reports

The query

```
select * from db_accessadmin.customerSummary 
where 
(accountNumber = $P{accountNo} or $P{accountNo}='')
and (ppuserMobile = $P{mobileNo} or $P{mobileNo}='')
and ( ppuserStaticID = $P{customerId} or $P{customerId} = '')
and (cast(requestDate as date) between (cast($P{fromDate} as date)) and (cast($P{toDate} as date)))
```

The aim is to generate a report in jasper depending on the values of the parameters. When the parameters 'fromDate' and 'toDate' are empty , the query should pull out the entire rows in the DB.
How can I modify the query so that it accepts null values for 'fromDate' and 'toDate'.

XML File

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="customerSummary2" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d23efc9c-641e-4e8a-bb9e-25673ee5c713">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.610510000000001"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<parameter name="accountNo" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="mobileNo" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerId" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="fromDate" class="java.util.Date">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Date()]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="toDate" class="java.util.Date">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}+7]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select * from db_accessadmin.customerSummary where (accountNumber =         $P{accountNo} or $P{accountNo}='')
 and (ppuserMobile = $P{mobileNo} or $P{mobileNo}='')
 and ( ppuserStaticID = $P{customerId} or $P{customerId} = '')
 and (cast(requestDate as date) between (cast($P{fromDate} as date)) and (cast($P{toDate} as date)))]]>
</queryString>
```

Comment: If this is a stored procedure you can give them default values. In fact, your query is weak as it is because you are accepting strings as date parameters and casting them to dates. Not only does that slow down production, it could cause errors if strings that don't represent valid dates get submitted.

Comment: I have saved the date as String in db for displaying the date and time in a special format. This code is meant for testing purposes. I would like to know how i should modify the code so that i can pass empty data. If its empty , it shouldn't search using date.

Answer (score 1):

This issue only occurs when i design the report in jasper iReport. But once i deploy it in the server, the issue is resolved. The server accepts null values.

Comment: That is great news. I'm not sure why it's not working in iReport. I wonder if it has anything to do with recasting those strings as dates?

Comment: I think thats the same reason. have to cast and recast the dates so that i can display it in a proper format.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to:

```
 select * from db_accessadmin.customerSummary 
 where 
 (accountNumber = $P{accountNo} or $P{accountNo}='')
 and (ppuserMobile = $P{mobileNo} or $P{mobileNo}='')
 and ( ppuserStaticID = $P{customerId} or $P{customerId} = '')
 $P!{date_sql}
```

Here's how I would do it in iReport, with Groovy, so you will have to modify this for Java. Create another parameter called date_sql, of type text, with the default value expression:

```
 ($P{fromDate}.isEmpty() || $P{fromDate} == null) 
 && ($P{toDate}.isEmpty() || $P{toDate} == null) 
 ? "and 1=1" : "and (cast(requestDate as date) between (cast("+$P{fromDate}+" as date)) and (cast("+$P{toDate}+" as date)))"
```

This is untested, so you might have to play around with the first part of the default value expression. But essentially, when the parameters are empty or null, return 1=1 (so, do not constrain by date) but if the parameters have values, use those values. What if your user enters one date but not the other? Maybe change the &&/AND to ||/OR and return 1=1 in that case.

Comment: The code works fine as long as i keep the date fields empty. But upon giving any of the dates , it fetches the entire database. And if i disable prompting 'date_sql' , it shows an error.

Comment: I revised the code above to put $P{fromDate} and $P{toDate} outside of the quotation marks. See if that helps.

Comment: I tried that but still yeilds the same result. Trying different iterations. No matter what date range i give ,it fetches the entire DB. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure $P{date_sql} is declared after $P{fromDate} and $P{toDate}.

Comment: This issue only occurs when i design the report in jasper iReport. But once i deploy it in the server, the issue is resolved. A third parameter date_sql is not required then. Thanks.